# Ghost blog development problems

Tags: css, content-management-system, blogs, ghost-blog

I'm working with a client who requires per minute changes and want to see live. I was working on static and using dropbox for quick updates in html files. Now I installed ghost client requires updates and see them again and again.

I've purchase ghost hosting and I also installed ghost on my local pc. The question is:

1. How may I able to modify css of my live blog http://livehelpapp.ghost.io/
2. When my client agrees and finalizes this blog. How could I be able to download those updated files from ghost.io server and handle that files to client?
3. If I develop / iterate on my local computer. How my client would be able to see changes?

Regards
Sheikh Naveed

Answer (score -2):

This is probably a bit late, but to answer each of your questions:

1) You are able to modify the css of your ghost blog once in the ghost folder by navigating to content/themes/*yourtheme*/assets/css/*.css. Rather than altering an existing theme you may want to create your own, and there are several [good tutorials](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-ghost-stages-of-design--webdesign-15895) on [how to do this](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/10/how-to-create-a-theme-for-ghost/).

2) You would need to send the theme you create to them so that they could upload it to their server running node w/ghost. Since ghost isn't the easiest CMS to set up (at least form a client perspective), you may find the easiest option is to upload the theme to a hosting platform (in your case the official ghost hosting)for your client and then just transfer the login details when the work is finalised so that they can add posts etc.

3) Rather than setting up your home computer as a temporary web server, you will probably find the easiest way to do this is to make alterations to the theme and then upload this to your chosen hosting platform (you can find how to do this in the settings tab on the admin section of your blog). If your client really requires by the minute changes, the other option is to create a dummy html page with an example article, upload this to dropbox and make css and html alterations as you have been doing. Then once your client is happy, you can turn the resulting file into a ghost theme that you can then upload.

Hope that helps.